# Download file: truncated

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, download

We have an ASP.NET/C# 2.0 (.NET 2.0) web application.

To make the client to download a byte array programmatically we have a piece of code which looks like this:

```
Response.ContentType = contentType ?? "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);    

Stream iStream = ...
byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];

while (dataToRead > 0)
{
  // Verify that the client is connected.
  if (response.IsClientConnected)
  {
    // Read the data in buffer.
    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

    // Write the data to the current output stream.
    response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
    response.Flush();

    //buffer= new Byte[10000];
    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
  }
  else
  {
    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
    dataToRead = -1;
  }
}

Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

This works on all our installations but one (on IIS 6) where I got files **truncated** (about 30KB). Did you ever experience such a problem?

Comment: This may be a client problem. Have you tried to use different browsers?

Comment: onof you figure this out in the end?

Comment: I found that the problem was related to a module, so it's not reproducible. So i flagged it to the moderator to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a module. We solved with `Response.End()` to prevent the execution of the module.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said where `dataToRead` is coming from.

Personally I'd just read until `length` returns a value <= 0, i.e. there's no more data to read.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
while (true)
{
    int length = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (length <= 0)
    {
        break; // There are alternative ways of expressing this
    }
    output.Write(buffer, 0, length);
}
```

Comment: dataToRead is computed by an algorithm that i haven't posted for brevity, anyway it's not the problem because I saw in the log that is bigger than the file actually downloaded. Thank you anyway

Comment: @onof: Why bother computing it? Is the client actually going to send more data than you want? Have you got logging to indicate whether you went into the `else` blocK?

Answer (score 0):

I've only used [`Response.BinaryWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite.aspx) than going direct to the OutputStream in past without fault.

I would have resisted the buffer control flushes and closes, let the Response instance manage buffering, closure etc. too.  And that loop seems a little unusual - I've usually read until no more bytes returned by the stream.

Comment: I put that loop because the stream to send could be very very large (although not in this case).

Comment: Yeah I understand the buffer, and not loading the whole stream into memory.  I was pointing to normally using NumBytesRead > 0 as my normal loop condition, where NumBytesRead is the result of  Stream.Read(buffer, offset, count)